# How to switch the Seed-ConfigNode in the cluster of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently constructing the cluster version of Apache IoTDB, and I noticed that I need to start one ConfigNode as `Seed-ConfigNode` to create the new cluster. I want to know if the `Seed-ConfigNode` of IoTDB can be switched, and if allowed how to switch this node?